# How to set scrollable in a iframe to iOS devices without a parent div

Tags: ios, html, css, iframe

Do you guys know if have a way to do iframe scrollable for iOS devices?

The inside page has scroll events, which if I use a div to wrapper, my code will break then **I can’t use a parent div for scrolling**.

Comment: By default I assume `iframe { overflow:scroll;}` is supposed to do the trick. Could you share some of your code maybe?

Comment: The problem is that we can't set a fixed height for the iframe, the content of iframe will be the height, i'ts like height: auto, so overflow: scroll will not works.